# display of array of objects in a table doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

Html Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>
    Some Mysterious People
  </title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"> -->
  <script src="dataService.js"></script>
  <script src="populateTable.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>What dorm were these people in?</h1>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Ph #</th>
      <th>Picture</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="rows">
    <!-- <tr>
        <td>
        Vic Norman
        </td>
        <td>
        M
        </td>
        <td>
        1818 Very-very Wealthy Street
        </td>
        <td>
        54
        </td>
        <td>
        (616) 555-3776
        </td>
        <td>
        <img src="" />
        </td>
    </tr> -->
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button  onclick="addDataRows()">Fetch Data</button>
</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript Code
DataService.js

```
    class DataService {
    constructor() {
      }
    
    data = [{
      name: "Clarence",
      gender: "Nonbinary",
      address: "1234 1st Grand Rapids, MI",
      age: 45,
      phoneNumber: "123456790"},
      { name: "Kwami",
      gender: "Male",
      address: "6432 5th Grand Rapids, MI",
      age: 21,
      phoneNumber: "9782603214"
      }]
    getData(numRecords = null){
      if(numRecords==null){
        return this.data
      }
      else{
        var i;
        const returndata = [];
        for(i =0; i <numRecords; i++){
          returndata.push(this.data[i]); 
        }
        return returndata;
      }
      }
}

module.exports.DataService = DataService;
//ds = new DataService();
//console.log(ds.getData(1));
```

populateTable.js

```
var ss = require("./dataService.js");
var ds =new ss.DataService();

function addDataRows() {
    ds = new ss.DataService();
    results = ds.getData();
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    html+="<tr>";
    html+="<td>"+results[i].name+"</td>";
    html+="<td>"+results[i].gender+"</td>";
    html+="<td>"+results[i].address+"</td>";
    html+="<td>"+results[i].age+"</td>";
    html+="<td>"+results[i].phoneNumber+"</td>";
    html+="</tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("rows").innerHTML = html;
}
```

I having trouble with displaying an array created in DataService.js. I am unable to display that on the dom. I attempt to be able to display this using the add rows function in populateTable.js. I am wondering if the issue lies in how I am using the document.getElementById function.

Comment: How are you serving this code? There are no issues with the javascript used to modify the DOM it works just as expected. Are you using Browserify? The require statement in populateTable.js should fail when you run this code in a browser if you are not using a tool like browserify to convert that piece of the code to something the browser can run natively.

Comment: i dont see any issue in code. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mydnj1t8/) also works fine. can you share error from developer tools if you are getting any?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use 'document.getElementById("rows").innerHTML = html;' and found it ok.
So I think you can make sure there is no error in F12 console. Debug your code is also a nice way to find the problem.

Wish you a good day!